# view is not getting refreshed with updated model

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angularjs-digest

My angular view is not getting updated when model changes. Model is getting changed in "onblur" event in directive.

`inputNgEl.bind('blur', function () {
})`

My model is being passed to a directive and directive is displaying the content of the model.

Please find the plunk below.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ku5yOyWsa1fjnLIs2Eu3?p=preview

Can you please advise what is missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Ur scope variable only acts as a glue between model and view... So define your variable in scope(In model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following change worked for me.

`inputNgEl.bind('blur', function () { 
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(ValidateControl);
                }, 0, false);
            });`

Corrected plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/kSnZbgY5AiaSfQxjbQke?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't know about your model changes: you need to trigger a digest by using [scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

```
// only apply the has-error class after the user leaves the text box
inputNgEl.bind('blur', function () {
    //el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
    //helpText.toggleClass('hide', formCtrl[inputName].$valid);
    scope.$apply(ValidateControl);

    // Or
    //scope.$apply(function () {
    //    ValidateControl();
    //});
});
```